# Android camera fails taking a picture every second

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-service

Let me start by saying that if image shooting interval is anything more than 1 second it works. For example taking a picture every 2 seconds works perfectly fine. But taking a picture every second **sometimes** throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed`. What could be causing this kind of a behaviour?

Here is the code I use and it is in **Service**:

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("general",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    handler = new Handler();

    shotInterval = prefs.getInt(getString(R.string.prefs_int_imageShootingFrequency),1);

    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        cameraId = findBackFacingCamera();
        if (cameraId < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
        }
    }

    cameraParameters = camera.getParameters();
    cameraParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE); //set camera to continuously auto-focus
    camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);

    pictureTaker.run(); // Start looping
}

Runnable pictureTaker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            takePicture();
        } finally {
            // 100% guarantee that this always happens, even if
            // your update method throws an exception
            handler.postDelayed(pictureTaker, shotInterval*1000);
        }
    }
};

private void takePicture(){
    SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.takePicture(null, null,new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say that the camera is not yet ready to take the next picture when you call ```takePicture```. 1 second interval seems pretty fast to me.

Comment: I have seen programs (that are not using camera2 API) that do that successfully. What is weird is that it sometimes works and sometimes doesnt.

Comment: Those programs might be running different hardware though. Your camera might just be slower.

Comment: No I mean I have tested them on my device as well. Also I have a flagship android device.

Answer (score 1):

You should launch `postDelayed()` from the [`onPictureTaken()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html#onPictureTaken(byte%5B%5D,%20android.hardware.Camera)) callback. You can check the system timer on call to `takePicture()` and reduce the delay respectively, to keep 1000ms repetition, but maybe once in a while, this delay will reach 0.

Comment: isn't `onPictureTaken()` part of camera2 API?

Comment: No, please follow the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html#onPictureTaken(byte%5B%5D,%20android.hardware.Camera))